# How do I get Twitter4J to stream posts with a certain hashtag?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

When I search for a given hashtag, I get the results for recent tweets containing that hashtag. This is what I want to stream, So if any new tweets with this hashtag are made I will know.

Comment: just use the search with the hashtag as a parameter?

Comment: Check out the FilteredQuery as demonstrated in this link http://davidcrowley.me/?p=435 . Just put your hashtag as a filter keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
try {
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query("#myhashtag"));
} catch (TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/search/SearchTweets.java)

You may need to escape the `#` symbol